# e learning system to upload pdf file for different users

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, open-source, moodle

I want to develop an e-Learning system for one of my client. The main  features are as follows:

1.students can register and log in using valid email id, password.

2.Logged on users can able to see only the PDFs files uploaded by the admin and can edit the document     file uploaded by the admin.

3.Document/PDFs can be uploaded by admin under various category, which students can see contrariwise.

I just wanted to know is there any other open source free content management system to develop such system or i have to develop it through PHP and MYSQL (Because i know PHP-MYSQl). Is it better to develop through MOODLE??? Please suggest

Comment: Moodle will do all of that and its probably the most widely used open source e-learning system. Its a mature product and there is a very active community too. The only downside is that it doesn't use a PHP framework so there is a bit of a learning curve - saying that all of the questions above are already done for you so you wouldn't need to do any development. The main docs are here http://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Main_page and the developer docs are here http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Main_Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chandra,

There are a number of different pieces of software out there that potentially could be moulded into what you are describing.

Moodle will do most of what your asking, and wordpress with the correct plugins could also.

I'm sure drupal will have some plugins that could make this happen also.

I think what you really need to do is look at what your trying to achieve and what your budget ( both financial and time ) is.

If you require all the functionality you suggest and its not possible to get this from opensource, or off the shelf software, then you will need to build something bespoke.

If however, you are happy to settle with a couple of items missing, there is more than liekely something you can purchase or download that will meet your needs.